# Need to create a padded, 100-character string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I need a 100-character string so my data will upload to a database.

For example, if A1 has the text "workshop", I need Excel to show the word workshop followed by 92 spaces. If I have the phrase "1 hour presentation", I need Excel to show the phrase followed by 81 spaces.

Comment: VBA can probably handle this.  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(A1,REPT(" ",100)),100)
```

It adds 100 characters to the end of your value, and then gets the leftmost 100 characters of the combined string.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is in cell A1, try:

```
=A1&REPT(" ", MAX(100-LEN(A1),0))
```

This will add enough spaces after your text to pad it out to 100 characters. Or, if your text is over 100 characters, it will leave the text unchanged.